# implement toolbar buttons in one activity

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-toolbar, android-button

I'm learning how to use Android Studio and the Kotlin language. I created a toolbar in which there are two buttons (search and share). I created an activity where the "search" button works and another activity where the "share" button works. Now, I would like to create an activity where both buttons work. What should I do?

```
//toolbar
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/main_menu"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Training">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
        android:title="@string/search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/share"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            android:title="@string/share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_share_24" />
</menu>

//search
package com.example.training
import android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.ListView
import android.widget.SearchView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.MenuItemCompat

class SearchActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var listView: ListView? = null
    var list: ArrayList<String>? = null
    var adapter: ArrayAdapter<String>? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search)

        listView = findViewById<View>(R.id.listafrutta) as ListView
        list = ArrayList()
        list!!.add("Mango")
        list!!.add("Avocado")
        list!!.add("Papaya")
        list!!.add("Kiwi")
        list!!.add("Maracuja")
        list!!.add("Ananas")
        list!!.add("Lici")
        list!!.add("Banana")

        adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, simple_list_item_1, list!!)
        listView!!.adapter = adapter }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        val inflater = menuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
        val searchViewItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search)
        val searchView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchViewItem) as SearchView
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
                searchView.clearFocus()
                if(list?.contains(query)!!){
                    adapter?.filter?.filter(query)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "No Match found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
                return false
            }
            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
                adapter!!.filter.filter(newText)
                return false
            }
        })
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
}

//share
package com.example.training

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class ShareActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_share)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) { // uso switch case perché è possibile avere più icone
            R.id.share -> {
                val sharingIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                sharingIntent.type = "text/plain" // tipo di content da condividere
                val shareBody = "Body message" // Body del content
                val shareSubject = "Subject Here" // puoi condividere qualsiasi cosa
                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody) // qui passo il body
                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, shareSubject) // e poi passo il subject
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"))
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have both the searchView and the share button on the toolbar your activity must look like the this:

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var listView: ListView? = null
    var list: ArrayList<String>? = null
    var adapter: ArrayAdapter<String>? = null
    lateinit var searchView: SearchView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        listView = findViewById<View>(R.id.listafrutta) as ListView
        list = ArrayList()
        list!!.add("Mango")
        list!!.add("Avocado")
        list!!.add("Papaya")
        list!!.add("Kiwi")
        list!!.add("Maracuja")
        list!!.add("Ananas")
        list!!.add("Lici")
        list!!.add("Banana")

        adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list!!)
        listView!!.adapter = adapter
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
        val searchViewItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search)
        searchView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchViewItem) as SearchView
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
                searchView.clearFocus()
                if (list?.contains(query)!!) {
                    adapter?.filter?.filter(query)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "No Match found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show()
                }
                return true
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
                adapter?.filter
                adapter!!.filter.filter(newText)
                return false
            }
        })
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.share -> {
                val sharingIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                sharingIntent.type = "text/plain" // tipo di content da condividere
                val shareBody = "Body message" // Body del content
                val shareSubject = "Subject Here" // puoi condividere qualsiasi cosa
                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody) // qui passo il body
                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, shareSubject) // e poi passo il subject
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"))
                true
            }
            else -> {
                super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So basically you are taking both implemenations of yours and combine them in one. Notice that we have created a global variable that is called searchView. We created a global variable in order to have access to the created view in the `onOptionsItemSelected`.

And this is how my menu looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/main_menu">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default"
        android:title="search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/share"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="share"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share" />
</menu>
```

I used the `app:showAsAction="always"` so that they both are displayed always. Its not considered a good practice but I think its necessary.

Let me know if you need more help

Comment: Thank you very much for helping. When I tried to create the code for the first time, the list did not appear, but now it does!
Both buttons appear, however only the share button works. What could be causing the problem?

Comment: Sure no problem. I've updated the MainActivity code, now it is working. The problem was that I was creating the Listener in the onOptionsItemSelected instead in the onCreateOptionsMenu. I would suggest you to watch some tutorials tho in order to get a better grasp of how things work :) 

(If this works and helped you out, make it as the right anser.)